# variable in data segment changes, if other variable(s) are defined

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, i386

All code is written for linux 32 bit

Why does it happens?

### If other variable(s) aren't defined, var(it) is 0

```
section .data
it: dw 0
```

### If other variable(s) are defined, var(it) isn't null

```
section .data
help_msg:      db "Usage: asmfuck <filename>", 0xa
file_error_msg db "Failed to open file", 0xa
it: dw 0
```

### Debuger output

Program fall down in second loop iteration in interpreter

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThKJi.png)

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFO1m.png)

[screenshot 3(var(it) changes here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVJLJ.png)

### Full code listing

- https://pastebin.com/NCv90Wyf - main file
- https://pastebin.com/b3fB9NiA - second file

Comment: Quick glance - `dw` represents a 16-bit value, not a 32-bit one, but you have code that attempts to access it as a 32-bit value like `inc dword [it]` . Maybe you meant `inc word [it]` or you meant to define `it` as `it: dd 0` . This would hold true in any other place you use `it` or any other values in memory. The `inc dword [it]` just ws the first one I spotted.

Comment: Do not put your code into a pastebin. Please put your full code into your question or even better, make a minimal *self-contained* example. Your example is small but not self contained as it does not show the issue you describe.

Comment: From the picture 3 it actually shows the it didn't change at all, it's still 0 word. But `add eax,dword [it]` does add to `eax` both `it` and first two bytes of `cells`, which when used as single `dword` value forms value `0x10000`. Decide what your data types are, and use them as such (either extend `it` to `dword`, or `add ax,[it]` to use it as `word` only).